# How can I count unique 2 word phrases that are seperated by a comma within a cell in R?

Tags: r, corpus

I have a dataframe of different locations (`Location`) along with the species of animals (`Spp`) found at each location. The species of animals are coded using their unique ***Genus species*** names. I would like to be able to know how frequent each unique ***Genus species*** is in the dataframe.

Example Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 3))
x <- c("Location","Spp")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$Location <- seq(1,3,1)
df1[1,2] <- c("Genus1 species1")
df1[2,2] <- c("Genus1 species1, Genus1 species2")
df1[3,2] <- c("Genus1 species1, Genus1 species2, Genus2 species1")
```

Output should look something like this

```
            Spp Freq
Genus1 species1    3
Genus1 species2    2
Genus2 species1    1
```

I have tried using the `corpus` package to answer this problem but can only get it to work on counting the unique words rather than the unique ***Genus species*** phrase.

```
library(tm)
library(corpus)
library(dplyr)

text <- df1[,2]
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
docs <- docs %>%
  tm_map(removePunctuation)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
matrix <- as.matrix(dtm)
words <- sort(rowSums(matrix), decreasing = TRUE)
words ### only provides count of unique individual Genus and species words. I want similar but need to keep Genus and species together.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick solution:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 3))
x <- c("Location","Spp")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$Location <- seq(1,3,1)
df1[1,2] <- c("Genus1 species1")
df1[2,2] <- c("Genus1 species1, Genus1 species2")
df1[3,2] <- c("Genus1 species1, Genus1 species2, Genus2 species1")

table(unlist(strsplit(df1$Spp,', ')))
#> 
#> Genus1 species1 Genus1 species2 Genus2 species1 
#>               3               2               1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Or `table(unlist(str_split(df1$Spp, pattern=", ")))` with the `stringr` package

Answer (score 1):

We may use `separate_rows` with `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   separate_rows(Spp, sep = ",\\s+") %>%
   count(Spp, name = 'Freq')
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Spp              Freq
  <chr>           <int>
1 Genus1 species1     3
2 Genus1 species2     2
3 Genus2 species1     1
```